# Tracking outgoing http requests from a web server

Tags: linux

I want track all outgoing HTTP requests from my server. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Nice question, but better suited to another stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using tcpdump it will look something like this:
tcpdump -i eth0 port 80

Answer (score 0):

Yes: tcpdump or wireshark (GUI).